# Converting a string to a date in DB2

Tags: casting, db2, date

I am working with a DB2 database for the first time.

I am trying to work with DB2 dates, but the data is stored as a string in the DB2 database.

I want to convert this date-string into an actual date, preferably dropping off time because I want all transactions between 1 Jan 2011 and 26 Jan 2011.

So essentially, I want this MS SQL statement in DB2 magic...

```
CONVERT(datetime,SETTLEMENTDATE.VALUE,103)
```

For background, I have got as far as

```
CAST(SETTLEMENTDATE.VALUE, DATE)
```

AND

```
DATE(SETTLEMENTDATE.VALUE)
```

But I need the expert knowledge of a DB2 whizzkid!

Thanks

Comment: i wish our dates were strings in our DB2...they're integers!  and there's 6 number dates (YYMMDD) (and 8 number dates (YYYYMMDD) - the solution to the Y2K issue!)....so in the 6 number dates the value 111 is really January 11, 2000...talk about messy conversions!

Comment: Could you post sample data from the SETTLEMENTDATE.VALUE column?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on your own answer, I'm guessing that your column has data formatted like this:

```
'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'
```

The actual separators between Day/Month/Year don't matter, nor does anything that comes after the year.

You don't say what version of DB2 you are using or what platform it's running on, so I'm going to assume that it's on Linux, UNIX or Windows.

Almost any recent version of DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows (8.2 or later, possibly even older versions), you can do this using the `TRANSLATE` function:

```
select 
   date(translate('GHIJ-DE-AB',column_with_date,'ABCDEFGHIJ'))
from
   yourtable
```

With this solution it doesn't matter what comes after the date in your column.

In DB2 9.7, you can also use the `TO_DATE` function (similar to Oracle's TO_DATE):

```
date(to_date(column_with_date,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
```

This requires your data match the formatting string;  it's easier to understand when looking at it, but not as flexible as the TRANSLATE option.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for this answer. I knew there must be a better way than what I was doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I know its old post but still I want to contribute
Above will not work if you have data format like this 
 `'YYYMMDD'` 

For example:

```
Dt
20151104
```

So I tried following in order to get the desired result.

```
select cast(Left('20151104', 4)||'-'||substring('20151104',5,2)||'-'||substring('20151104', 7,2) as date) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Additionally, 
If you want to run the query from MS SQL linked server to DB2(To display only 100 rows).

```
    SELECT top 100 * from OPENQUERY([Linked_Server_Name],
    'select cast(Left(''20151104'', 4)||''-''||substring(''20151104'',5,2)||''-''||substring(''20151104'', 7,2) as date) AS Dt 
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1')
```

Result after above query:

```
Dt
2015-11-04
```

Hope this helps for others.

Comment: You could also do the following if your date column is an integer datatype formatted like YYYYMMDD (e.g. 20230522), and not a character string:

    SELECT
    
        DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(your_int_date_column),'YYYYMMDD'))  AS "DatefromInteger"

Answer (score 1):

In format function your can use timestamp_format function.
Example, if the format is YYYYMMDD you can do it :

```
select TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(yourcolumnchar, 'YYYYMMDD') as YouTimeStamp 
from yourtable
```

you can then adapt then format with elements format foundable [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_timestampformat.html)

Comment: Note, if your date column is an integer datatype like YYYYMMDD, and not a character string (e.g. 20230522), you will need to use something like:

    SELECT
    
        DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(your_int_date_column),'YYYYMMDD'))  AS "DatefromInteger"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems like a bit of a hack. I have got it to work using a substring, so that only the part of the string with the date (not the time) gets passed into the DATE function...

```
DATE(substr(SETTLEMENTDATE.VALUE,7,4)||'-'|| substr(SETTLEMENTDATE.VALUE,4,2)||'-'|| substr(SETTLEMENTDATE.VALUE,1,2))
```

I will still accept any answers that are better than this one!

Comment: While this hacky way of doing things works, please see Ian Bjorhovde's answer, which I have accepted above!

Answer (score 0):

Note, if your date column is an integer datatype like YYYYMMDD, and not a character string (e.g. 20230522), you will need to use something like:

```
SELECT

    DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(your_int_date_column),'YYYYMMDD'))  AS "DatefromInteger"
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use:

```
select VARCHAR_FORMAT(creationdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') from table name
```

Comment: I believe they're asking for string to date and not date to string