# to_date with AS400

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, to-date, db2-400

I am writing to you because I can't use the operator `to_date` on an AS400 database.

With Oracle database, I use:

```
datefield >= to_date('01/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

But with AS400, I get an error:

> Incompatible operator

Is there another function I may use to replace `to_date`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in DB2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852139/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-db2)

Comment: I want to specify that I want to put it in a where condition..

Comment: In your WHERE condition, are you trying to convert a database value stored as dd/mm/yyyy into a date for the comparison, or do you plan to compare against a specific date such as dates less than '06/30/2014'

Answer (score 5):

assuming datefield is a actual date data type

Then all you need to do is use an ISO formatted date string

```
datefield >= '2014-01-01'
```

DB2 for IBM i will always recognize '2014-01-01' as a date.

But if you really want to explicitly convert it yourself, then there's two functions

```
DATE('2014-01-01')
CAST('2014-01-01' as DATE)
```

CAST is preferred for portability.

I recommend sticking with ISO format, though the system will recognize USA 'mm/dd/yyyy' and EUR 'dd.mm.yyyy'.

Reference here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzdtstrng.htm

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Can you tell me how to use CAST ?
Because I have not been able to use it.
I put it in the WHERE condition, like "CAST('2014-01-01' to DATE)" or "CAST(datefield to DATE)" but it doesn't work.

Thanks lot !

Comment: @Olivierm67, are you sure that the date field you're comparing is truly a date field?  Old-school AS/400 programmers liked to store dates as numeric fields.

Comment: @Olivierm67 It would help if you (1) gave us the database definition of `datefield`, (2) told us precisely what you want to accomplish and (3) included any error message IDs and/or SQLSTATE/SQLCODE if some error was returned. Otherwise we're mostly in the dark.

Comment: Of course the OP should have given DDL and been clear about what failure, however: Neither of "`CAST('2014-01-01' to DATE)` or `CAST(datefield to DATE)`" would function because the syntax offered is incorrect; i.e. the "but it doesn't work" would almost surely be described by the msg SQL0199 "Keyword TO not expected. Valid tokens: AS."; thus @Charles, the part of the answer offering CAST should be modified to `CAST('2014-01-01' AS DATE)`  p.s. sorry I did not notice that when I added my first necro-post to the topic, but this comment can stand irrespective any update being made.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this topic is *old*, but the current answer seemed mostly to ignore the original issue with TO_DATE, and instead offer a circumvention; of course the circumvention is IMO, a better approach.  By addition of the message identifier and further explanation of the original issue and possible resolutions, hopefully those are beneficial to others in both locating this discussion as a match to their own issue and beneficial for the additional commentary provided.

The issue described in the OP is a reflection of the error condition SQL0401 [sqlcode -401] diagnosing that the data-type of the TO_DATE scalar is a TIMESTAMP whereas the DateField column data-type is a DATE [or so implied, although if the OP had included the DDL for the TABLE, the reviewers could be assured that "datefield" is indeed a column of the DATE data type].

In v5r3 the "Cause" is described by the text "Date, time, and timestamp operands are compatible with character operands or with another operand of the same type."; FWiW the USEnglish [first-level] text likely would have been "Comparison operator >= operands not compatible.", rather than just "Incompatible operator" as was noted in the OP.  Even by v7r1, the documentation suggests no change for the SQL0401:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzala/rzalaml.htm

> "...
>   
> Date, time, and timestamp operands are compatible with character and graphic operands or with another operand of the same type.
>   
>  ..."

Despite the name of the scalar function, for what might seem the logical effect given that moniker, the scalar result is **not** a DATE data type; the effect is instead reflective of the scalar function name TIMESTAMP_FORMAT, thus yielding a TIMESTAMP scalar result.  The moniker TO_DATE is merely a synonym\syntax-alternative:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscatsformat.htm

The originally described scenario `datefield >= to_date('01/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')` for which a non-standard date format is coded, the error could be prevented by explicitly casting the result of that TO_DATE scalar to a DATE type.  For example by wrapping the TO_DATE result in another [casting] scalar, such as for example, either of the DATE casting scalar
 `datefield >= DATE(to_date('01/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))`
 or the CAST scalar
`datefield >= CAST(to_date('01/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') as DATE)`

Of course the other alternatives of using a character-string formatted as one of the *standards* date formats [e.g. *ISO as Charles suggested] is probably just as simple; even if that usage is not as explicitly revealing [to a reviewer of the statement] as would be the *format-string* specified as the second argument on the TO_DATE().  But per the specification originally shown as 'DD/MM/YYYY', the preference may be to use the *EUR standard formatting for which the format is 'DD.MM.YYYY'; i.e. coded as `datefield >= '01.01.2014'`

Note that in addition to the **Date strings** documentation reference http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzdatestrings.htm, there is another alternative not mentioned on that page which is a somewhat redundant form of the *ISO formatted character-string, `DATE '2014-01-01'` and almost the same [both in specification and redundancy; the alternative merely saves typing the parentheses] as the DATE [casting] scalar specification `DATE('2014-01-01')` already mentioned elsewhere in this topic.  Thus each of `datefield >= DATE'2014-01-01'` or `datefield >= '2014-01-01'` or `datefield >= DATE('2014-01-01')` are all equivalent, and each is depending on *ISO formatting of the character-string as the date representation.

Comment: Note that by IBM i 7.3, perhaps earlier, the effect of comparing a TIMESTAMP to a DATE will no longer result in the error "***incompatible operands***" thus rendering moot, the original concern expressed in the OP