# SQL : DB2 Maximum and minimum value of date on 3 columns ( Day, Month, Year)

Tags: sql, db2, max

I'm working on SQL DB2, I would like to retrieve field with once the maximum value of date, but the date is on three columns (Day, Month, Year).

Can you please help me with?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what have you tried? You can concatenate the columns to form the date

Comment: combine the columns as strings thenc ast to date then use max on the combined column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852139/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-db2

Comment: SELECT  YEAR, MONTH, DAY FROM FILE  WHERE YEAR = (select MAX(YEAR) from FILE) ==> But this will only return the date with the maximum year. I want to retrieve the maximum date. I dont know how u can concatenate since it's numeric fields can u please give me more explanation

Comment: use rank() over(order by year desc, month desc, day desc) statement

Comment: What is the type of fields DAY, MONTH, and YEAR?

Comment: It's Numeric fields and im trying to retrieve may columns not just that one. and among them the most recent date.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please:

```
select distinct year, month, day
from (
    select year, month, day, rank() over(order by year desc, month desc, day desc) as rn
    from [your table name]
) t
where rn = 1
```

**UPDATE1:**
If you have some field with contract number, then you need to use *partition by* statement in *over()*

```
select distinct contract_number, year, month, day
from (
    select contract_number, year, month, day, rank() over(partition by contract_number order by year desc, month desc, day desc) as rn
    from [your table name]
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: It works but im trying to retrieve other columms along with and from other files also when I add other columns it doesnt work

Comment: Fazah, you try to add columns from other tables? How this structure is look?

Comment: Actually I'm using many tables and I need to retrieve fields having many conditions one of them is the maximum date an other is the minimum date etc...

Comment: @Fazah, so, what's problem? This query return 1 string, you can join it and select only that you need. If in the same time you need other strings, use left join.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in the way i displayed the problem, I'm gonna give you an example : I have many contracts in my table C1 has a date like this : Day : 01 month : 02 year : 2017 and C1 has another a date like this : Day : 01 month : 01 year : 2017 and other contracts like this one. What I need to do is to retrieve the contract : C1 with the max date for this contract which is Day : 01 month : 02 year : 2017 and the same or the other contrats so I will have C1 with its max date and C2 with its max date so on. I hope I more clear now and thx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. But you need to change below query with the format that you are using in day,month,year format.

```
select * from urtable where to_date(year||'-'||month||'-'||day,'yyyy-mon-dd') in 
(select max(to_date(year||'-'||month||'-'||day,'yyyy-mon-dd'))) from urtable )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable
order by colyear desc, colmonth desc, colday desc
fetch first rwos only
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in the way i displayed the problem, I'm gonna give you an example : I have many contracts in my table C1 has a date like this : Day : 01 month : 02 year : 2017 and C1 has another a date like this : Day : 01 month : 01 year : 2017 and other contracts like this one. What I need to do is to retrieve the contract : C1 with the max date for this contract which is Day : 01 month : 02 year : 2017 and the same or the other contrats so I will have C1 with its max date and C2 with its max date so on. I hope I more clear now and thx a lot for your help. –