# DB2: substring a number

Tags: db2

In my dataset I have a variable (numeric) which is year+month, called *year_month* with values 201702, 201703 etc.

Normally my code looks like this:

```
select 
year_month
,variable2
,variable3
from dataset
```

I wish to extract the month and the year from the year_month variable, but I'm not sure how to do this when *year_month* is numeric.
**edit**: not a duplicate, different problem, I do not care about dates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852139/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-db2)

Comment: ... _why_ do you want to do this?  If you're wanting to query only a specific range (only a certain year, for example), putting this in a `WHERE` clause, you'd be better served by constructing the bounds, since restricting based on a function usually invalidates the use of an index.  If this is only for final display, then you should be fine.

Comment: not to be rude, but the simple answer is: because I *can*. I'm learning, and trying to take in as much information as I can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the date parts from an integer

```
SELECT year_month/100,MOD(year_month,100)
```

To fully convert the integer to a date :

```
SELECT TO_DATE(CHAR(year_month),'YYYYMM')
```

Comment: int(year_month/100) as year and year_month%100 as month did not work. just gave me errors. Maybe it is something with my formats in db2

Comment: Use `MOD(a,b)` instead of `a%b` operator

Answer (score 2):

Possible with this methods too:

```
select left(cast(year_mont as varchar(6)), 4) as YYYY,                    
right(cast(year_mont as varchar(6)), 2) as MM from yourtable
```

You can have a timestamp like this:

```
select TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(cast(year_mont as varchar(6)), 'YYYYMM') as YouTimeStamp 
from yourtable
```

Or a date too:

```
select Date(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(cast(year_mont as varchar(6)), 'YYYYMM')) as YouTimeStamp 
from yourtable
```